# Verify proof that $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^z \frac{t^m}{1+t}dt = 0 : z\in\mathbb{C}, |z|=1.$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

**To Prove:**

$\displaystyle \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^z \dfrac{t^m}{1+t}dt = 0 : z\in\mathbb{C}, |z|=1.$

**My Real Question:** Is the following analysis valid?

**My Research:**
I know little about complex analysis.  I (superficially) browsed some online texts and 
(given $z=x+iy : x,y\in\mathbb{R}$), decided to **construe**

$\;\displaystyle \int_0^z \dfrac{t^m}{1+t}dt \;$ as 
$\;\displaystyle\left(\int_0^x \dfrac{t^m}{1+t}dt\right) 
\;+ i\times \left(\int_0^y \dfrac{t^m}{1+t}dt\right).$

**My Work:**

Since $|z|=1,\;|x|\leq 1\;$ and $\;|y|\leq 1.\;$ Further,
when $\;m>0,$

$\displaystyle \left\lvert\int_0^x \dfrac{t^m}{1+t}dt\right\rvert < \left\lvert\int_0^x t^m dt\right\rvert 
\;= \left\lvert\;\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}\right\rvert$ 
and

$\displaystyle \left\lvert\int_0^y \dfrac{t^m}{1+t}dt\right\rvert < \left\lvert\int_0^y t^m dt\right\rvert \;= \left\lvert\;\frac{y^{m+1}}{m+1}\right\rvert.$

Since $\;|x|\leq 1\;$ and $\;|y|\leq 1,$ 
$\;\left\lvert\dfrac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}\right\rvert\;$ and 
$\;\left\lvert\dfrac{y^{m+1}}{m+1}\right\rvert\;$ 
both go to zero as $\;m\rightarrow\infty.$

Therefore $\;\displaystyle \left\lvert \int_0^z \frac{t^m}{1+t}dt\right\rvert\;$ goes to zero as $\;m\rightarrow\infty.$

**Correction:**

The above analysis assumes (for example) that as $t$ ranges from $0$ to $x,$ $\dfrac{1}{1+t} < 1.$  This is true when $x>0,$ but **false** when $x<0.$

**However,** if $-1 < x < 0,\;$ then as $t$ ranges from $0$ to $x,$ $\dfrac{1}{1+t} < \dfrac{1}{1+x}.$

This provides a remedy for the analysis except in the special cases of $x=-1$ or $y=-1.$ This forum query was originally intended as the final piece of analysis needed for a 2nd query: [Request help verifying the Taylor series expansion of $\text{ln}(1 + e^{2ix})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969592/request-help-verifying-the-taylor-series-expansion-of-textln1-e2ix).

In the 2nd query, $\ln(1+z)$ is **disallowed** when $z=-1,$ but allowed when $z=-i.$  Thus, **even if my correction is valid,** it still remains to prove (in the 2nd query) that $\displaystyle \ln(1-i) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} (-i)^{k+1}.$

This means that for marty cohen's answer in the 2nd query to apply, it must be shown that the $\displaystyle \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^{y} \frac{t^m}{1+t}dt = 0,$ specifically when $y=-1.$  **I would love feedback here.**

**2nd Correction:**

I have augmented the 2nd query: [Request help verifying the Taylor series expansion of $\text{ln}(1 + e^{2ix})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969592/request-help-verifying-the-taylor-series-expansion-of-textln1-e2ix), to manually resolve the case of $z = -i,\;$ which is the only pending case  unresolved by my first **Correction.**

I don't know if $\int_0^z \dfrac{t^m}{1+t}dt\;$ exists when $z=-i,\;$ and **would still like feedback on this.**  **However,** with respect to the 2nd query, the issue is **moot.**

Comment: I just realized my original logic is flawed and have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: If $z=-1$ the integral is not defined.

Comment: @zhw if z = -i, is the integral **also not defined?**

Comment: I have added a 2nd correction to the question to reflect that the special case of $z=-i$ may be considered moot with respect to the *original query* which this query is supporting.  However, I would still like feedback on the special case of $z=-i.$

Comment: There is no problem with $z=-i;$ the problem is with $z=-1,$ which needs to be excluded.

Comment: @zhw does this mean that my analysis/logic is valid except when $z=-1$ or $z=-i,$ and that more sophisticated analysis is needed to cover $z=-i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|z|=1,z\ne -1,$ we have

$$\tag 1 \left |\int_0^z \dfrac{t^m}{1+t}dt\right|=\left | \int_0^1 \frac{(sz)^m z}{1+sz}\, ds\right | \le \int_0^1 \frac{s^m }{|1+sz|}\, ds.$$

Now for $s\in [0,1],$ $|1+sz| = |sz-(-1)|.$ The last expression is the distance from $sz$ to $-1,$ which is bounded below by the distance from the line segment $[0,z]$ to $-1.$ This last distance is a positive number I'll call $d_z.$ It follows that the right side of $(1)$ is bounded above by

$$\frac{\int_0^1s^m\,ds }{d_z}= \frac{1}{d_z(m+1)}\to 0.$$

This shows the left side of $(1)$ $\to 0,$ which is the desired result.

Comment: very interesting, thanks.  I understand everything in your answer except how you justify eqn (1).  For example, is $\;\left\lvert\int_0^1 \frac{s^m z^{m+1}}{1 + sz}ds\right\rvert \;= \;\left\lvert z^{m+1}\right\rvert  \times \left\lvert\int_0^1 \frac{s^m}{1 + sz}ds \right\rvert$?

Comment: my bad, I just answered my own question.  apparently, $\left\lvert \int_a^b f(z)dz \right\rvert \;\leq \int_a^b \left\lvert f(z) \right\rvert dz.$

Comment: I especially like that your answer helped me to **visualize** why all values of $z$ with $|z|=1$ are permitted except for $z=-1.$  It is because when $z=-1, d_z = 0.$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> I'll introduce a *slight* modification. Namely,
>   $\ds{z \in \braces{\vphantom{\Large A}z \in \mathbb{C} \left.\vphantom{\large A}\right\vert \verts{z} = 1}\setminus\color{red}{\braces{-1}}}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
\lim_{m \to \infty}\int_{0}^{z}{t^{m} \over 1 + t}\,\dd t &
\,\,\,\stackrel{t\ =\ zx}{=}\,\,\,
\lim_{m \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}{z^{m}x^{m} \over 1 + zx}\,z\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1 - x}{=}\,\,\,
\lim_{m \to \infty}\bracks{z^{m +1}\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - x}^{m} \over 1 + z\pars{1 - x}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{m \to \infty}\bracks{z^{m +1}\int_{0}^{1}
{\exp\pars{m\ln\pars{1 - x}} \over 1 + z\pars{1 - x}}\,\dd x}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> With
>   [Laplace Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method):

\begin{align}
\lim_{m \to \infty}\int_{0}^{z}{t^{m} \over 1 + t}\,\dd t & =
\lim_{m \to \infty}\bracks{z^{m +1}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\exp\pars{-mx} \over 1 + z}\,\dd x}
=
{1 \over 1 + z}\,\lim_{m \to \infty}{{z^{m +1} \over m}}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\large 0}\quad
\mbox{because}\quad\bbox[10px,#ffd]{0 < \verts{z^{m + 1} \over m} = {1 \over \verts{m}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ m\ \to\ \infty}{\LARGE\to} {\LARGE 0}}
\end{align}

Comment: Very interesting response, thanks.  I unsuccessfully tried to grasp the Laplace Method through several online sources, so I can't express an opinion on your answer.

Comment: @user2661923 In line $\left(1\right)$ you can see that the 'main contribution' to the integral, when $\displaystyle m \to \infty$,  comes for values of $\displaystyle x \gtrsim 0$. So, it's sufficient to use $\displaystyle \mathrm{e}^{-mx}$ instead of $\displaystyle \exp\left(m\ln\left(1 - x\right)\right)$ while $\displaystyle x$, in the denominator is set to zero. That's Laplace Method. For the same reason the integration is 'extended' to $\displaystyle\infty$.

Comment: thanks for trying.  I would probably have to study complex analysis for some time to be clear on why your steps were valid.